# Why some SE websites are updated more regularly than others

Tags: discussion

Some websites like Stack Overflow are updated almost instantly in terms of profile updates, badges etc. but others like Super User or Area 51 are not. For example, when I vote on some questions, the number of my votes is almost instantly updated on my profile in Stack Overflow but this can even take up to 30 minutes in Super User. why is it like that? I've also noticed that the number of questions on Stack Overflow are much more than Super User.

Comment: Caching. Always.

Comment: It happens on a newly installed browser too.

Comment: @Saeed server-side caching, not browser caching

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your base assumption is plain wrong.

The votes tab of the profile (assuming that's what you mean) is updated **instantly** on **all sites**.

For example, here is a fresh screenshot taken on Super User:

> [image]

Not half an hour, not 20 minutes, not even one minute - one second.

If you mean the "Votes Cast" stat in profile page, it's being updated **at random intervals**, something like 5-60 minutes, regardless of the site. I did a quick test, and on Super User it was updated after 8 minutes, while in Stack Overflow 15 minutes passed and it's still not updated. The reason for this random interval is lowering the chance of people guessing who the user voted for.

Comment: I didn't mean that. in profile page the "Votes cast" doesn't change instantly and it takes more than 30 minutes to be updated. it also happens in other situations where the user must vote 300 times to get a specific badge. i did that in SO and i got the badge in less than 1 minute but in SU it took up to 1 hour. it also happens in other similar badges too.

Comment: @Saeed please see my edit.

Comment: Yes that seems pretty much right to be the reason for the delay. thank you.